# Http Params does not append in get request

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

app.module.ts

```
getHttpParams = () => {
    const httpParams = new HttpParams();
    console.log(this.userForm.controls)
    Object.keys(this.userForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        console.log(this.userForm.get(key).value)
        const value = this.userForm.get(key).value;
        if (value){
            console.log('keyvalue' + httpParams.append(key, value)) ==> It Showing corrrect value
            httpParams.append(key, value);      ==> HttpParams map return null
            console.log(httpParams)
        }
    });
    return httpParams;
}

onSubmit() {
    this.router.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        let opts = { params: this.getHttpParams() }
        console.log(opts)

        this.http.get<User>(`${this.serverUrl}`, opts).subscribe(
            res => {
                this.user = res
                console.log(res)
            }
        ),
        console.log(params);
    })
}
```

When getHttpParams function calls, it is getting correct value but `httpParams.append` returns null in httpParams Map. Can anyone help me out??

Comment: [HttpParams](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#description), from the documentation "This class is immutable; all mutation operations return a new instance.". It means when you use `.append` you have to reassign httpParams like `httpParams = httpParams.append(key, value)`

Comment: @Lievno thanks it works, but what a stupid design choice from google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HttpParams append method will return new body with the appended value.

```js
getHttpParams = () => {
let httpParams = new HttpParams();
Object.keys(this.userForm.controls).forEach(key => {
  const value = this.userForm.get(key).value;
  if (value){
    httpParams = httpParams.append(key, value); // 
    console.log(httpParams)
  }

});
return httpParams;
}
```

read this article [Creating a URL with HttpParams in Angular](https://medium.com/@armno/creating-a-url-with-httpparams-in-angular-42783205f3f4) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create an HttpParams object from another object, see below:

```
getHttpParams = () => new HttpParams({ fromObject: this.userForm.value });
```

Simple and elegant!

Comment: Earlier, i used this method but i want if any item returns null then it should not add in params

Comment: In this case, you can filter the null values from this.userForm.value and then use this method.